# Elastic Search Synonym filter behaviour is different when applied at analyzer filter compared to multiplexer level

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, kibana

Synonym filter i.e ***my_synonym*** when i applied at Analyzer level is working as expected

```
PUT /test_index?pretty
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
             "my_synonym" 
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "foo, bar => baz",
              "The hero => CaptainAmerica"
            ]
          },
          "my_multiplexer": {
            "type": "multiplexer",
            "filters": [
              "my_synonym"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And when execute

```
GET /test_index/_analyze?pretty
{
   "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "The hero bar"
}
```

i am getting below output which is what i am expecting

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "CaptainAmerica",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "baz",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i apply ***my_synonym*** filter to ***my_multiplexer*** and injecting ***my_multiplexer*** to analyzer filter is yielding different results

```
PUT /test_index?pretty
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "my_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "my_multiplexer"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "my_synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "foo, bar => baz",
              "The hero => CaptainAmerica"
            ]
          },
          "my_multiplexer": {
            "type": "multiplexer",
            "filters": [
              "my_synonym"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the result for same query is

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "The",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 3,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "hero",
      "start_offset" : 4,
      "end_offset" : 8,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "bar",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "baz",
      "start_offset" : 9,
      "end_offset" : 12,
      "type" : "SYNONYM",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I observed that if i use coma (,) in place of whitespace ' ' in synonym list it is working as expected but i need to join few words and link to single entity.

Please let me know what went wrong or other workarounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the issue.**

Apparently, I am facing of a side effect of the "remove duplicates" filter used at the output of the Multiplexer filter. In the code of the "remove duplicates" filter, we can see:

`boolean duplicate = (posIncrement == 0 && previous.contains(term, 0, length));`

**Workaround :**

Replace the "contains" String method by the "equals" in the test of the "RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilter"